# How to get global variables defined in top-level module in a function?

Tags: python, python-module

I want to implement `@noglobal` [^1](https://gist.github.com/raven38/4e4c3c7a179283c441f575d6e375510c) decorator in a module.

However, the `globals()` builtin function gets global variables in the module where `globals()` called [^2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals).

How to get global variables defined in the top-level module, within a function?

### What I did

```py
# in ./lib/utils.py
import builtins
import types


def imports():
    for name, val in globals().items():
        # module imports
        if isinstance(val, types.ModuleType):
            yield name, val

            # functions / callables
        if hasattr(val, "__call__"):
            yield name, val


"""
usage: If @noglobal decorator is specified, the function throws an exception if global variables are used in it.

ref: https://gist.github.com/raven38/4e4c3c7a179283c441f575d6e375510c
"""


def noglobal(f):
    return types.FunctionType(
        f.__code__, dict(imports()), f.__name__, f.__defaults__, f.__closure__
    )
```

```py
# in ./main.py
import pandas as pd
from lib.utils import noglobal


@noglobal
def get_pandas_version():
    return pd.__version__


get_pandas_version()
```

```
# output
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [18], line 6
      1 @noglobal
      2 def get_pandas_version():
      3     return pd.__version__
----> 6 get_pandas_version()

Cell In [18], line 3, in get_pandas_version()
      1 @noglobal
      2 def get_pandas_version():
----> 3     return pd.__version__

NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

### The expected output

`main.py` shouldn't throw exception because `pd` global name is defined in the top module.

---

### What obtained by `globals()` is different according to where the function is  defined

```py
# ./lib/utils.py
def get_globals():
    return globals()
```

```py
# ./main.py
from lib.utils import get_globals


set(globals().keys()).difference(set(get_globals().keys()))
```

```
# output
{'In',
 'Out',
 '_',
 '__',
 '___',
 '__builtin__',
 '_dh',
 '_i',
 '_i1',
 '_i2',
 '_ih',
 '_ii',
 '_iii',
 '_oh',
 'exit',
 'get_ipython',
 'get_pandas_version',
 'open',
 'pd',
 'quit'}
```

Comment: `pd` is not defined, maybe you are missing some kind of `import pandas as pd`?

Comment: Sorry, but I just mistyped the code section. Pandas are imported by `import pandas as pd`.

Comment: From the official Python documentation regarding the globals() function, it is set at the time a function is defined, not when its called:
"Return the dictionary implementing the current module namespace. For code within functions, this is set when the function is defined and remains the same regardless of where the function is called."
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals

This infers that within your imports function, its global namespace doesn't include other modules imported within your main.py script. Maybe add some print/logging to debug it?

Comment: As you pointed out, the main issue is `globals()` builtin function doesn't return global variables in the context where it is called. That means moving `globals()` from a top level module to other module changes output. This makes implementing @noglobal decorator as a module impossible. It would come to easy if any alternative to `globals()` where it returns global variables in the run-time context.

Answer (score 1):

**In header section just type import this one. Problem will be fix**

```
import builtins
import types
import pandas as pd
```

note if pandas are not installed then install it by this command from your terminal

```
pip install pandas
```

Comment: Sorry, but I just mistyped the code section. Pandas are imported by import pandas as pd.